# Post data and get response from URL for login is not working

Tags: ios, http-post, httpresponse

In my application, I have login process and for that, I'm passing the **username** and **password** to **php script** and getting response. But the problem is, after getting the response I'm not able to move on to the next view controller or show the message.Need some guidance to resolve this issue.

**This is my current code.**

```
    - (IBAction)submit:(id)sender 
      {
         NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/IOS/login/getres.php?username=%@&password=%@",usern.text,pass.text];
         NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
         NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"%@",strResult);

         if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"succuss"]) 
         {
             UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"loged in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert1 show];
             [alert1 release];
         }
      }
```

If I print the response, I can see the success message but still I don't why its not working.I am not able to make out where I'm going wrong in my above code.

Thanks.

Comment: [strResult isEqualToString:@"succuss"]) , check the spelling. pls upload ur response

Comment: please check the spelling of succuss, as the right spelling is success.

Comment: @Suhail i have checked spelling and i have changed now but still its not working

Comment: Plz upload response also.or NSLog(@"%@",strResult);

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300353/nsurlrequest-post-data-and-read-the-posted-page. May help you.

Comment: @Suhail please check i have updated my question

Comment: what is  NSLog(@"%@",strResult) s content

Comment: @Suhail  im getting success is my  response please check my edited question

Comment: i saw that.also i want to know strResult. if it is @"success", it shold work.

Comment: @Suhail that result only im telling if i give corrent username password im getting success is my response in strResult

Comment: i can't c any problem in ur code..if strResult== @"success".ur code should work.

Comment: Please check my answer it will solve your problem. And if solved please rply.

Comment: Just to note that your code doesn't POST and that you should at least be using https to offer the user some kind of security...

Comment: @Wain thanks will look in to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are having two lines above your output so trim the string by \n and spaces.

```
    strResult=[strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n "]];
```

it will definetly work

Comment: If in future you get such problems please use breakpoints. They gonna help you a lot.