# How to send data to server in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am a beginner to ios development.
Can anyone tell me how to send data to server in xcode?
I have a requirement where I need to send device information to a server.

Comment: just search in stack, before posting here..

Comment: Xcode is just an editor, in which language are your developing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first work out what kind of API the server you're talking to has exposed

Most modern web applications expose a Rest API (although I can only speculate as to what the server you mention is exposing).  If Rest, then a good starting point should you not wish to write your own network layer is to use Restkit: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

If not Rest, then you need information on what the backend API is, and then go from there...

Answer (score 0):

In it's most basic format you'll need to look at using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`

[NSURLRequest : Post data and read the posted page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300353/nsurlrequest-post-data-and-read-the-posted-page)

http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/